# How to GET data in the JSON format form the DB Repository

Tags: json, spring-boot, jpa, get, spring-data-jpa

I have this JPA Class, where I have 3 columns **id**, **name** and **date**. The Database is already filled with data, where each entry has an id.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "TESTSCHEMA")
public class TestDataJpaRecord implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    TestDataJpaRecord(){
        // default constructor
    }

    public TestDataJpaRecord(
       String name,
       Date date,
    ){
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "TEST_SEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            sequenceName = "TEST_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1,
            name = "TEST_SEQUENCEx")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;
}
```

I created a JPA repository for all the data.

```
public interface TestDataJpaRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<TestDataJpaRecord, Long> {
}
```

I want to get the data from the DB in a JSON format. 
Here is my Rest GET Api. Here I return the data as a string just, but I want to return them as JSON.

```
@GetMapping(value = "data/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<?> getDataFromTheDB(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        // get one entry form the DB
        TestDataJpaRecord testDataJpaRecord =testDataJpaRecordRepository.findOne(id); 

        // Here I want to return a JSON instead of a String 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(testDataJpaRecord.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Any idea on how I could return the data as JSON and not as a string from the DB?
I would very very much appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Don't call toString `new ResponseEntity<>(testDataJpaRecord, HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: @AlanHay Unfortunately I get this error: 
 ` "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jackson on the classpath which you should if you have used the spring-boot-starter-web then simply:

```
@GetMapping(value = "data/{id}")
private ResponseEntity<TestDataJpaRecord> getDataFromTheDB(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    TestDataJpaRecord testDataJpaRecord =testDataJpaRecordRepository.findOne(id); 
    return new ResponseEntity.ok(testDataJpaRecord);
}
```

This assumes you have annoted your controller with `@RestController` rather than `@Controller`. If not then you can either do that or, annotate your controller method with `@ResponseBody`.

With Spring Data's web support enabled (which it should be by default with Spring Boot) then you can also simplify as below:

```
@GetMapping(value = "data/{id}")
private ResponseEntity<TestDataJpaRecord> 
         getDataFromTheDB(@PathVariable("id") TestDataJpaRecord record) {
    return new ResponseEntity.ok(record);
}
```

See:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.domain-class-converter

Comment: I have annotated  the controller @RestController, but unfortunately I get the following error: 
 "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle

Comment: Well that is a whole other question which has been answered many times. See here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: I read the article, it was about entities with bidirectional relationship, which is not my case. My class has no relationships to other classes...

Comment: You would need to post the full entity because the error indicates it has a reference to another record of the same type. https://www.google.com/search?q=JsonMappingException:+Direct+self-reference+leading+to+cycle+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_v-HtzbjnAhVUShUIHU-yArYQrQIoBDAAegQIBhAO&biw=2048&bih=1010